# how to iterate through some children's of every id in Firebase Database android (java)?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have one parent that is shop and in that every id is a shop and i want to iterate through every id means every shop and store the object of `shop_details` because i want to show every shop in `RecyclerView`

here is my database Hierarchy

[image]

Here is my partial code but this is not working

```
ArrayList<Shop_details> list=new ArrayList<>();

database.getReference("Shops").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        list.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            Shop_details shop_details = postSnapshot.getValue(Shop_details.class);
          
            list.add(shop_details);
          
        }
        shop_list_adapter adapter=new shop_list_adapter(list,getContext());
        shop_list_recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
        shop_list_recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        Loading_box.dismiss();
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Shop_details` class matches the JSON structure in the `shop_details` node of the database, you should read the object from only that snapshot:

```
Shop_details shop_details = postSnapshot.child("shop_details").getValue(Shop_details.class);
```

---

Note that it may be better to store the separate aspects of a shop in separate top-level nodes, all with the same key for each shop. Something like:

```
shop_details: {
  "igd1P...": { owner_name: "...", shop_address: "...", ... },
  "yDLoU...": { owner_name: "...", shop_address: "...", ... }
},
shop_services: {
  "igd1P...": { ... },
  "yDLoU...": { ... }
}
```

That way you can load just the details of each shop, without also loading all their services. This type of structure also allows you to secure the data better.

I recommend reading up on [structuring your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data) specifically on [avoiding nested data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data) and [flattening your data structures](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#flatten_data_structures).